# How to run a Linear Regression in R with a dataset from BigQuery?

Tags: sql, r, google-bigquery, linear-regression

I connected BigQuery Dataset with RStudio by running the following lines of code in RStudio.

```
install.packages("bigrquery")

library(bigrquery)
library(DBI)

con <- dbConnect(
  bigrquery::bigquery(),
  project = "MyProjectID",
  dataset = "MyDataset"
)
test<- dbGetQuery(con, sql, n = 10000, max_pages = Inf)


sql <- "SELECT * FROM  `MyProjectID.MyDataset`" 

tb <- bigrquery::bq_project_query("MyProjectID", sql)
bq_table_download(tb, max_results = 10)
```

And now, I wanted to run a linear regression analysis. I used the following to build a regression model.

```
model_fit = lm(event_n ~ geo_country,
           data = "`MyProjectID.MyDataset`")
```

But it's giving me the error, "'data' must be a data.frame, environment, or list"

Could anyone help me fix this? Thanks a lot!

Comment: "`MyProjectID.MyDataset`" is just a string (character variable). What variable holds the data from the BigQuery table? That's what you should be using for `data`.

Comment: I think your `data = "`MyProjectID.MyDataset`"` should be `data = tb`

Comment: I used data = tb and I got this error: "cannot coerce class ‘"bq_table"’ to a data.frame"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to assign the result from `bq_table_download` to a data frame variable. For example:

```
mydata <- bq_table_download(tb)
```

And then:

```
model_fit = lm(event_n ~ geo_country,
               data = mydata)
```

[See this guide](https://songjoyce.medium.com/bigquery-basics-connecting-to-bigquery-in-r-d08a3fb246a7).